# Error "Data at the root level is invalid" after transformation, while doing a LoadXML

Tags: vb.net, xslt, xmldocument

I am trying to do some XSLT transformation, to convert an XML to XML, using the following lines of code. When i try to create an XMLDocument object from the transformed XML i am getting an error

Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

```
 Dim outputXML As New XmlDocument

        Dim stream As New MemoryStream
        Dim writer As XmlTextWriter = New XmlTextWriter(stream, System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.UTF8)

        Dim navigator As XPathNavigator = illustratePlusXML.CreateNavigator()
        Dim transormer As XslCompiledTransform = New XslCompiledTransform()
        transormer.Load(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("XSLT_File_Path"))
        transormer.Transform(navigator, Nothing, writer)

        Dim output As String = System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray())
        outputXML.LoadXml(output)

        Return outputXML
```

I could find a special character(square box), i persume this is causing the error. attached snapshot of the output xml. Can somebody please suggest ?

[image: output xml with special character]

Comment: I think you won't have these problems if you use the (default for XslCompiledTransform) utf-16 encoding.

Comment: Have you tried to open the XmlTextWriter without specifying the encoding?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev My XMl is using UTF-8 encoding, should i still try the default encoding ?

Comment: @Anoop, I think that you don't need to use MemoryStream at all. When characters are read from a file, they are converted to .NET, and any .NET character is in UTF-16 -- so, this is done automatically for you and you shouldn't care and do anything in addition to this.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Thanks for your help. Yes that worked, with the code given by Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to populate an `XmlDocument` as the result of an XSLT transformation then simply do

```
Dim resultDoc As New XmlDocument()
Using xw As XmlWriter = resultDoc.CreateNavigator().AppendChild()
        Dim navigator As XPathNavigator = illustratePlusXML.CreateNavigator()
        Dim transormer As XslCompiledTransform = New XslCompiledTransform()
        transormer.Load(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("XSLT_File_Path"))
        transormer.Transform(navigator, Nothing, xw)  
        xw.Close()
End Using
```

There is no need to use a MemoryStream. If you really think you need to use a MemoryStream then make sure you reset its `Position` to `0` before calling the `Load` method.

Comment: Thanks! That works. Can you please suggest whats going wrong with the code posted in the question ? Am i doing the wrong encoding or is it the Memory stream position you mentioned ?

Comment: I think the problem is with the encoding and a byte order mark getting into your way. If you want to use a MemoryStream then write to it and simply allow the XML parser to load from it with e.g. `memStream.Position = 0 : resultDoc.Load(memStream)`.